# IOEerror in python "No such file or directory"

Tags: python, django, file

I am writing a django project that involves retrieving data from a table. I have a module that has the line to retrieve some data (snp_data.txt is a file on the same directory of the module)：

```
  data = file("snp_data.txt")
```

While the module works well when I call it separately outside the django project; I keep getting the error below, when I call with other module within the django app.

```
  no such file or directory as 'snp_data.txt'
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: The way that you passed "snp_data.txt" in is a relative path - relative to where you're running your script.

Comment: Instead of `data = file("snp_data.txt")` I would change the text file to the actual path. It should be `data = file("Path\to\snp_data.txt")`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are trying to open the file in the *current* working directory, because you didn't specify a path. You need to use an absolute path instead:

```
import os.path
BASE = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

data = open(os.path.join(BASE, "snp_data.txt"))
```

because the current working directory is rarely the same as the module directory.

Note that I used `open()` instead of `file()`; the former is the recommended method.