# Python OpenCV -- How to open a file?

Tags: python, opencv, video

In openCV, with python, how do you open a video file?

Currently I have:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Superman-01-The_Mad_Scientist.mp4')
```

and my .mp4 is in the same folder as this script. When I `print cap.isOpened()`, I get false. How do you properly open this file?

Another thing I have tried:

```
BASE = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
the_file = open(os.path.join(BASE, 'sample_video','Superman-01-The_Mad_Scientist.mp4'))

print the_file.__str__()
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(the_file)
print cap.isOpened()
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
<open file 'C:\dev\sample_video\Superman-01-The_Mad_Scientist.mp4', mode 'r' at 0x02482288>
  File "C:/dev/test.py", line 9, in <module>
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(the_file)
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Which means its looking for a camera, but the tutorial and API says it takes a filename as input as well.

Comment: Not the script location, but the *current working directory* determines where a file is found when using a relative path.

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15146584/100297) help, for example?

Comment: I tried that though with the path. Do I have to open the file using OS then pass that variable into the function? The API says "filename" as a string.

Comment: Is this Windows or another OS? If on Windows, did you use single backslashes as path separators perhaps?

Comment: The technique in the other answer sidesteps any issues with backslashes in Python strings, btw.

Comment: I am familiar with that method, and I updated my code to show you what happens when I try it.

Comment: You passed in an open file object, **not** a filename. Pass in `os.path.join(Base, 'sample_video', 'Superman-01-The_Mad_Scientist.mp4')` (which is an absolute path).

Comment: cap.isOpened() still returns false though.

Comment: I am not familiar with `opencv` itself; no idea how it treats the filename.

Answer (score -1):

try add str convertion

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(str(the_file))
```